# Nested List with Javascript (TCPDF)

Tags: javascript, html, css, tcpdf

I am facing a problem in a couple of weeks and I could not figure out.

I have an ordered list and it is nested.

```html
<html>
     <head>
      <style>
       OL { counter-reset: item }
       LI { display: block }
       LI:before { content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item }
      </style>
     </head>
     <body>
     <ol>
        <li>Number One</li>
        <li>Number Two
          <ol>
             <li>Number Two - One</li>
             <li>Number Two - Two</li>
             <li>Number Two - Three</li>
          </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Number Three 
          <ol>
             <li>Number Three - One</li>
             <li>Number Three - Two</li>
                <ol>
                   <li>Number Three - Two - One</li>
                   <li>Number Three - Two - Two</li>
               </ol>
          </ol>
        </li> 
        <li>Number Four</li>
      </ol>
     </body>
    </html>
```

However, I need an approach using Javascript (because these CSS rules is not working on TCPDF).

**So, I can't figure out how to implement a function using Javascript to modify these ol, li (nested elements - father and child) to add the numbering 1, 2, 2.1, 2.2, 3, 3.1, 3.1.2, 3.2.2 without CSS.**

I already know that I need to use something like:

```
<script>
 function
 ...
    getElementById('li')
    getElementsByTagName('li')
 ...
</script>
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Why are you trying to use something that vaguely looks like javascript inside a `<style>` tag?

Comment: @devius, see [css counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters). OP wants a different solution.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was typing and instead of script I wrote style...

Comment: Besides the obvious: "Why would you want do that without CSS, but with JavaScript?" > you need a recursive javascript function - but.. Why would you want to do that without CSS?

Comment: @trincot I was talking about the part after "I already know that I need to use something like:"

Comment: pretty sure tcpdf doesn't parse javascript... it doesn't even have a full implementation of css, why would you expect it to understand javascript?

Comment: I think you need to do more research into JavaScript. Maybe take some tutorials on DOM manipulation. `getElementById` does just that, and none of your elements has an id attribute. [MDN has examples of using `getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName#Example) as I'm sure other sites do as well.

Comment: @Occam'sRazor I thought that if CSS is not working with HTML, I could use an approach with Javascript, because I cannot modify the default numbering in ordered nested list.

Comment: @BSants - Nope.. you will need to use PHP.. simple string handling..

Comment: or just change the static html file by hand... why isn't that an option in the first place?

Comment: @Occam'sRazor I am using php to retrieve data from a database directly in these ordered nested list. To modify directly in the database is not a good solution. So, I understood now that TCPDF has its limitations. Thank all of you guys, I will do some reputation.

Answer (score 1):

One, you have an inconsistency with your HTML, sometimes you nest child `<ol>` items inside a `<li>` and sometimes you do not. I've attributed this to a mistake and made a recursive function for you that acts as if you always nest them, you can find it below. It changes the HTML so you should have no issues.

The inconsistency I am talking about happens on 3-2-1 / 3-2-2, you closed the `<li>` tag for 3-2 before opening an `<ol>` tag which made `<ol>` become a 3-3

```js
var root = document.getElementsByTagName('OL')[0];

recur(root)

function recur(element, id, index) {
  id = id || "";
  index = index || "";
  if (element.tagName === "LI") {
    id = id ? (id + "." + index) : index;
    element.innerHTML = id + ". " + element.innerHTML;
  }
  Array.prototype.slice.call(element.children).forEach(function(el, ind) {
    ind++;
    recur(el, id, ind);
  })


}
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Number One</li>
  <li>Number Two
    <ol>
      <li>Number Two - One</li>
      <li>Number Two - Two</li>
      <li>Number Two - Three</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Number Three
    <ol>
      <li>Number Three - One</li>
      <li>Number Three - Two
        <ol>
          <li>Number Three - Two - One</li>
          <li>Number Three - Two - Two</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Number Four</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Awesome!!! However, the problem is that TCPDF has limitations and doesn't have all CSS and Javascript implementations. So, it will not work even though is correctly. I will give you a reputation but I can't give you a correct answer because it is in TCPDF.

Comment: Well I cannot do more then a pure javascript solution. This is as native as it gets m8. I am not sure what TCPDF supports so this is about as how close you can get without any external libraries or sources and whatnot. Thanks for +1, wish u best of luck